# prove by induction: $3 + 5 + 7 + ... + (2n+1) = n(n+2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

> Use the principle of mathematical induction to prove that $$3 + 5 + 7 + ... + (2n+1) = n(n+2)$$ for all n in $\mathbb N$.

I have a problem with induction.  If anyone can give me a little insight it would be helpful.

Comment: I know that the term before 2n+1 would be 2n+1-2 thus 2n-1

Comment: Have you set up a base case? How about an induction hypothesis?

Comment: yeah I am not helping myself too much. it is all relatively new to me.  Went over it today in class and didn't understand it just trying to help myself out.

Comment: so with the base case I just prove 3 can be represented as n(n+2). so n=1 in that case.

Answer (score 3):

If you already know that

$$1+2+3+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

we can try the following alternative approach:

$$3+5+7+\ldots+(2n+1)=$$

$$=1+2+3+4+5+\ldots+(2n+1)+(2n+2)-1-2(1+2+3+\ldots+ n+n+1)=$$

$$=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+3)}2-1-2\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}2=(n+1)(2n+3)-1-(n+1)(n+2)=$$

$$=(n+1)\left[2n+3-n-2\right]-1=(n+1)^2-1=n^2+2n=n(n+2)$$

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, but here's a little outline. Let $\displaystyle f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k+1).$ Then $f(1) = 3$.

And $\displaystyle f(n+1) = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(2k+1) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(2k+1)+2(n+1)+1 = f(n)+2n+3. $

Answer (score 0):

See the answers on [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080202055157AAaWcSi) and read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote above for the base case would work, assuming you state something to the effect that for $n = 1$, $2n + 1 = 2(1) + 1 = 3 = 1(1 + 2)$.  That is, you want to get the $2n + 1$ in there.

For the the induction hypothesis, you can proceed like so:  Assume that the identity is true for all $n \leq k$.  In this case, that means

$$3 + 5 + \ldots + (2k + 1) = k(k + 2)$$

Then you want to see if the identity holds for $k + 1$.  So:  What happens now if you add $2k + 3$ to both sides?  Can you factor the new right-hand side in any sort of helpful way?

If it turns out that, whenever the identity holds true for $n=k$, it also holds true for $n = k + 1$, then you can say it's true for all natural numbers.